# What phenomenon is used in Optical fibre?

Tags: fiber-optics

I want to know which phenomenon is used in fibre optics to transmit light rays. I visited http://en.wikipedia.org but did not find it. I also tried it on google but all in vain. Can anyone please tell me?

**ADDED:**

How is it possible to maintain a degree greater than critical angle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fibre optics ,a optical phenomenon known as [total internal reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection) is used to transmit light rays.

In case of the simplest form of optical fiber, light entering one end of the fiber strikes the boundary of the fiber and is reflected inward. The light travels through the fiber in a succession of zigzag reflections until it exits from the other end of the fiber.

In the other type of  optical fibers,they  are designed in such a way that the zigzagging of the light is greatly reduced or virtually eliminated.

Comment: But how is it possible to maintain a degree more than critical angle?

Comment: @ Pranit Bauva...I hope you are using some instrument.Am i right?

Comment: I am 15 years and I have seen it in a question paper of a school .... I don't have access to any of the fancy instruments .... I just want to clear my doubt about the critical angle!

Comment: http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/refrn/u14l3c.cfm....see this link

Comment: how do they maintain a degree greater than critical angle?

Comment: @PranitBauva: If the incident beam angle is greater than the critical one, then the beam will be partially lost at each reflection. The beam intensity will be fading with the distance, that's for sure.

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski Thanks! That cleared my doubt!